# Building a react native SDK to be used by IOS

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

I am building an SDK using react native to be used by native android and IOS apps. I was trying to make the SDK easy to be set up, so the SDK user does not have to use yarn or npm. Based on some blogs, android seems to be doable. However, with IOS i am having some troubles adding the react native dependencies.

[React native docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/next/integration-with-existing-apps) suggests adding pods using downloaded node modules. Is there any way for the SDK user to only add the SDK pod to his/her app without adding any react native pods? I am new to cocoapods and as far as i understand IOS searches for pods on the cocoapods repo only.

I tried uploading all the react native dependencies to a [public repository](https://github.com/AbdullahAsendar/react-native-ios-pod) so the SDK user can add all the pods to his/her Podfile. If someone wants to use the SDK the Podfile would look like this:

```
  pod 'MySdk', :path => '../my-sdk'

  repository = 'git@github.com:AbdullahAsendar/react-native-ios-pod.git'
  tag = '0.61.5'

  pod 'FBLazyVector', :git => repository, :tag => tag
  pod 'FBReactNativeSpec', :git => repository, :tag => tag
  pod 'RCTRequired', :git => repository, :tag => tag
  pod 'RCTTypeSafety', :git => repository, :tag => tag
  pod 'React', :git => repository, :tag => tag
  .... THE REST OF THE PODS
```

This may be acceptable but not having to add all these pods would be better,

Also, can i create a pod for each one of the dependencies and upload these pods to [CocoaPods](https://cocoapods.org/)? This way i would reference these pods in my SDK and the SDK user will only have to add the SDK pod.

Answer (score 0):

Incase anyone is interested, i ended up creating a [private Podspec repo](http://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods.html), which contains all the podspecs that i need for the SDK. All the podspecs are pointing to their original repositories. It looks like [this](https://github.com/AbdullahAsendar/react-native-ios-pod).

Now the SDK user will have to do the following:

On the terminal

```
$ pod repo add REPO_NAME SOURCE_URL
```

Inside the Podfile

```
source SOURCE_URL

pod YourSdkName
```

Edit:
I wrote a blog about it
https://asendar.medium.com/building-react-native-0-61-5-sdk-to-be-used-by-native-ios-applications-swift-481d38f549bb

Comment: I am trying to make the same thing, but I keep getting errors about multiple commands producing the same header files. If i use pods with relative path to node_modules folder everything works ok. If I use pods with podspecs from my own repo, I get errors. The react dependencies of correct version are downloaded successfully though. Have you encountered those errors?

Comment: @guest3523 i did not encounter such errors tbh, it went smoothly. if you want i can share my podfile with you

also, you might be interested in this: https://github.com/electrode-io/electrode-native

Comment: I beat those "multiple commands producing ..." errors. I was missing the correct paths in most of podspecs for s.source_files (I had like "*.{m,mm}" instead of "Libraries/Image/*.{m,mm}"). I used podspecs from the node_modules directory. Still I am getting some errors about missing header files. Definitely not smooth experience :) Do you declare any post install scripts in your podfile - releated to the react-native stuff?

Comment: @guest3523 ahhh.. i remember changing s.source_files in podspecs.... as i also used podspecs from the node_modules

what are the missing headers exactly? maybe you have to add them to source_files as well (eg: spec.source_files = 'double-conversion/*.{h,cc}')

Comment: if it helps i uploaded all my podspecs here: https://github.com/AbdullahAsendar/react-native-ios-pod

Comment: Currently Xcode screams for 'folly/Optional.h' file not found in RCTTypeSafety/RCTConvertHelpers.h while building RCTBlob target. I already used your repo for updating paths in source_files so thx for that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220365/discussion-between-guest3523-and-abdullah-asendar).

Comment: @AbdullahAsendar: Can you explain in slight detail how did you achieve this, Or if you have any link which explains this properly. That would be a great help.

Comment: @Zac24  i can write a blog about this if that helps

Comment: It would surely help. I would love to read that blog with every detail possible.

Comment: @AbdullahAsendar: Are you going to write that blog? eagerly waiting for that.

Comment: @Zac24 Sorry have been busy lately,, i will write something today.. will send you once i am done

Comment: @AbdullahAsendar: Sure, Do lemme know when you are done.

Comment: @AbdullahAsendar: Did you get some time to pen it down?

Comment: okay thanks, Please update once complete. thanks a lot.

Comment: @Zac24 apologies for being late, this is my very first blog, i hope it clears out everything.. i am happy to explain more anything that is unclear

https://asendar.medium.com/building-react-native-0-61-5-sdk-to-be-used-by-native-ios-applications-swift-481d38f549bb

Comment: @AbdullahAsendar: Thanks a lot, I'll check that out and will try to follow the same.

Comment: @guest3523 if you are still interested kindly check the blog at your convenience