# Integration React Native into existing Native iOS, getting pod install error

Tags: ios, swift, react-native

I am trying to install pod into iOS app with following pod file data -

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

# Required for Swift apps
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

# The target name is most likely the name of your project.
target 'EmbedRN' do
  # Your 'node_modules' directory is probably in the root of your project,
  # but if not, adjust the `:path` accordingly
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
    'Core',
    'CxxBridge', # Include this for RN >= 0.47
    'DevSupport', # Include this to enable In-App Devmenu if RN >= 0.43
    'RCTText',
    'RCTNetwork',
    'RCTWebSocket', # needed for debugging
    # Add any other subspecs you want to use in your project
  ]
  # Explicitly include Yoga if you are using RN >= 0.42.0
  pod "Yoga", :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga"

  # Third party deps podspec link
  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'

end
```

getting pod install error -

pod install
Analyzing dependencies
Fetching podspec for `DoubleConversion` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConv ersion.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `Folly` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `glog` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec`

[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "React/Core":
In Podfile:
React/Core (from `../node_modules/react-native`)

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `React/Core (from` ../node_modules/rea
ct-native`)`.

You have either:

- out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update` .
- mistyped the name or version.

Package.json file content -

```
{
  "name": "EmbedRN",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "0.63.0"
  }
}
```

Project structure -
[image]

Comment: i have done a similar thing a couple of months ago, i ended up creating a private podspec repo. This may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60084117/building-a-react-native-sdk-to-be-used-by-ios